# Apache Spark Java API + Twitter4j + exception while saving Twitter stream to Elasticsearch

Tags: java, apache-spark, twitter4j, elasticsearch-spark

I am trying to set up a Twitter stream using Apache Spark Java API. While saving the Twitter stream to Elasticsearch, I am getting an exception. I think I am trying to save raw tweet that is why the problem is. Please let me know what can I try to resolve this exception.

Following is the code:

```
package com.twitter.streaming;
import com.twitter.util.TwitterStreamUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils;
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark;
import twitter4j.Status;

/**
 * Created by Manali on 1/28/2017.
 */
public class TwitterStream {

    private static final String[] filters = {"#football"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // create the spark configuration and spark context
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\");
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTwitterStreamExample").setMaster("local[2]")
                .set("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.class.getName())
                .set("es.nodes", "localhost:9200")
                .set("es.index.auto.create", "true");

        // create a java streaming context and define the window (3 seconds batch)
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(15));

        System.out.println("Initializing Twitter stream...");

        // create a DStream (sequence of RDD). The object tweetsStream is a DStream of tweet statuses:
        // - the Status class contains all information of a tweet
        // See http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html
        // and fill the keys and tokens in the Streamutils class!
        JavaDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc, TwitterStreamUtils.getAuth());

        JavaDStream<String> statuses = twitterStream.map(
                new Function<Status, String>() {
                    public String call(Status status) { return status.toString(); }
                }
        );
        statuses.print();

        statuses.foreachRDD(tweets->{
                    // save tweet to Elasticsearch
                    JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(tweets, "spark/tweets");
                    return null;
                });

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1486397175000 ms
-------------------------------------------
StatusJSONImpl{createdAt=Mon Feb 06 10:06:11 CST 2017, id=828635913144016896, text='夢王國超強大的XDDD 
托托大愛( ´▽` )ﾉ
發棉花糖的執事超高超帥wwwww

#夢100 #CWT45',  rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', isTruncated=false, inReplyToStatusId=-1, inReplyToUserId=-1, isFavorited=false, isRetweeted=false, favoriteCount=0, inReplyToScreenName='null', geoLocation=null, place=null, retweetCount=0, isPossiblySensitive=false, lang='ja', contributorsIDs=[], retweetedStatus=null, userMentionEntities=[], urlEntities=[], hashtagEntities=[HashtagEntityJSONImpl{text='夢100'}, HashtagEntityJSONImpl{text='CWT45'}], mediaEntities=[MediaEntityJSONImpl{id=828635824715505665, symbolEntities=[], currentUserRetweetId=-1, user=UserJSONImpl{id=4298859732, name='草加美燕', screenName='mU7oEb6DVbCda4S', location='臺灣 新北市中和', description='17歲的高
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1486397175800
17/02/06 10:06:16 ERROR TaskContextImpl: Error in TaskCompletionListener
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89
 at [Source: [B@25c68cc; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:478)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:436)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:426)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:248)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.close(RestRepository.java:267)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService$PartitionWriter.close(RestService.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(EsRDDWriter.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anon$2.onTaskCompletion(TaskContextImpl.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:77)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/02/06 10:06:16 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6)
org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89
 at [Source: [B@25c68cc; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 7, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
17/02/06 10:06:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6, localhost): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89
 at [Source: [B@25c68cc; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 7)
17/02/06 10:06:16 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO BlockManager: Found block input-0-1486397172800 locally
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 3
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 7)
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 3 was cancelled
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (foreachRDD at TwitterStream.java:47) failed in 0.589 s
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 failed: foreachRDD at TwitterStream.java:47, took 0.608443 s
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1486397175000 ms.1 from job set of time 1486397175000 ms
17/02/06 10:06:16 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 1.086 s for time 1486397175000 ms (execution: 1.001 s)
17/02/06 10:06:16 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1486397175000 ms.1
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6, localhost): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89
 at [Source: [B@25c68cc; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in parsing tweet value. I use ObjectMapper for it following is the working code for saving the Twitter stream to Elasticsearch using Apache Spark.

```
package com.twitter.streaming;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.twitter.util.TwitterStreamUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils;
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark;
import twitter4j.Status;

/**
 * Created by Manali on 1/28/2017.
 */
public class TwitterStream {

    private static final String[] filters = {"#trumph", "#happy"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // create the spark configuration and spark context
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\");
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkTwitterStreamExample").setMaster("local[2]")
                .set("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.class.getName())
                .set("es.nodes", "localhost:9200")
                .set("es.index.auto.create", "true");

        // create a java streaming context and define the window (3 seconds batch)
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(15));

        System.out.println("Initializing Twitter stream...");

        // create a DStream (sequence of RDD). The object tweetsStream is a DStream of tweet statuses:
        // - the Status class contains all information of a tweet
        // See http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html
        // and fill the keys and tokens in the Streamutils class!
        JavaDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc, TwitterStreamUtils.getAuth());

       /* JavaDStream<String> statuses = twitterStream.map(
                new Function<Status, String>() {
                    public String call(Status status) {
                        return status.toString();
                    }
                }
        );*/
        //statuses.print();


        // Jackson ObjectMapper for parsing
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // parse and save Twitter stream to Elasticsearch
        twitterStream//.map(t -> new Tweet(t.getUser().getName(), t.getText()))
                .map(t -> mapper.writeValueAsString(t))
                .foreachRDD(tweets -> {
                    JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(tweets, "spark/tweets");
                    return null;
                });


        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```